# Array of pointers not changing after getting modified inside another function

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, embedded, dynamic-arrays

An array of pointers of chars is not getting changed in `main`.
Here's the situation: Inside `main`, an array of pointers of chars is declared and memory is allocated for it. `main` calls another function called `AddItems` which adds items to the list and that function calls `doubleSize` to double the size of the list. Everything is working as expected in terms of adding new items inside `AddItems` and doubling the size of the array. However, the problem is that when `AddItems` returns, main still has an older copy of the list, even though we're passing a pointer to the list.

Here's a MWE:

```
#define INITIAL_SIZE (4)
int main(void)
{
    char **list = (char **) malloc(INITIAL_SIZE * sizeof(char *));
    int list_size = INITIAL_SIZE;

    for (int i = 0; i < list_size; i++) {
        list[i] = (char *) malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(list[i], "jane");
    }
    printf("main--> address of list: %p\n", list); 
    /* output = 0x7fc15e402b90 */
    addItems(list, &list_size);
    /* After adding items: */
    printf("main--> address of list: %p\n", list); 
    /* output = 0x7fc15e402b90 (no change) */

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the other two example functions:

```
void doubleSize(char ***list, int *current_size)
{
    char **newList = (char**) malloc(*current_size * 2 * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < *current_size; i++)
        newList[i] = (*list)[i];
    free(*list);
    *list = newList;
    *current_size = (*current_size) * 2;
}
void addItems(char **list, int * size)
{
    printf("Before doubling: %p\n", list);
    /* Output: 0x7fc15e402b90 */
    /* Double the size */
    doubleSize(&list, size);
    printf("After doubling: %p\n", list);
    /* Output: 0x7fc15e402be0 */
}
```

The address of `list` is getting changed to the newly created array inside `doubleSize` and also inside `addItems` but not inside the main function, even though we're passing a pointer to the array. What am I missing here?

Comment: `addItems(list, ...` --> You need to pass the address of `list` to affect `list` inside `main`, or you can return the `realloc`ated pointer.

Comment: @DavidRanieri Oh but what about array decay? Doesn't the array decay to a pointer naturally? When we passing `list` to `addItems` we're passing a pointer of `list`, right?

Comment: Re "*Oh but what about array decay?*", You have no arrays.

Comment: @NightOwl this short snippet https://ideone.com/BAZGeU illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a function to change something, you need to pass its address (or use a global).

You didn't, so it couldn't. Simple as that.

---

At no point after the first line of `main` do you modify `main`'s `list`. Remember that C only passes the value of variables to functions (pass by copy), and that the value of the variable is the address of the allocated block.

If you want `addList` to be able to change `main`'s `list`, you will need to pass the address of the variable `list` itself (`&list`).

You're apparently aware of the concept since you did exactly that in `addList`. You wanted `doubleSize` to change `addList`'s `list`, so you passed its address to `doubleSize`.

---

Tip: It would be best to use `realloc` in `doubleSize`.

```c
void doubleSize(char ***list, size_t *size) {
    size_t new_size = *size * 2;
    char **new_list = realloc(*list, new_size);
    if (!new_list) [
        // Ignoring out-of-memory errors.
    }

    *list = new_list;
    *size = new_size;
}
```

Since we're ignoring out-of-memory errors, the above simplifies to

```c
void doubleSize(char ***list, size_t *size) {
    *list = realloc(*list, ( *size *= 2 ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also try as below by modifying `addItems`

```
char** addItems(char **list, int * size)
{
    printf("Before doubling: %p\n", list);
    /* Output: 0x7fc15e402b90 */
    /* Double the size */
    doubleSize(&list, size);
    printf("After doubling: %p\n", list);
    /* Output: 0x7fc15e402be0 */
    return list;
}
```

And the call from `main` should be:

```
list = addItems(list, &list_size);
```

Comment: Thanks @David Ranieri for editing my answer, of course its your suggestion

Comment: Oh, I didn't pay atention to the first line, you were already pointing out that, sorry